# Small AGV robot for ROS application

Tags: mobile-robot, ros

I am looking for an off-the-shelf small AGV which runs or could be used with ROS. It may include some basic sensors like a camera, an IMU, an Ultrasonic range finder, etc.

Really appreciate all the valuable suggestions from the community.

Comment: Can you give some more insight into what kind of AGV you are looking for? Or maybe what the intended application is?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Franky, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: @AkhilKurup I plan to teach a ROS course, so all I need a small four-wheel robot that could be controlled with ROS with some sensors I mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The turtlebot-3 is a good option. It comes in [two variants](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/overview/) and has basic sensors ideal for teaching/learning ROS. Clearpath has [several options](https://clearpathrobotics.com/robots/) ranging from small to large robots. These are the ones I am familiar with. If you are looking beyond these: [ros-robots](https://robots.ros.org/) has an official list of robots with intended capabilities listed out.

Also, there is the option of learning ROS in simulation using either Gazebo or something like [the construct](http://constructsim).